# Javascript Validation not working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have used some javascript for validation eg. allow only numbers or text, restrict length.it's working fine on desktop but on mobile below mention javascript is not working.

```
 /// allow numbers only  
 $('#pincode, #billing_phone').keypress(function (e) {
 //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
   //display error message
   return false;
  }
});


//allow characters only
 $(function() {
$("#billing_first_name, #billing_last_name").keydown(function(e) {
  if ( e.which != 9) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32)  || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
});

// restrict length
$("#reg_billing_city").attr('maxlength',30);
$("#billing_phone, #reg_billing_phone, .qty").attr('maxlength',10);
```

**What I have Tried:**

I have written my javascript according to screen width like this

```
if (screen.width < 600) {// javascript goes here }
```

and it's working fine on desktop but on mobile, it's not working.

Can you please help to identify the problem?

Comment: is the keycodes is same in web and mobile...?

Comment: yes everything is same, I have checked in the browser(for mobile resolution) and it's working fine but in actual mobile devices it's not working fine